# Update binding of static property

Tags: wpf, binding, static

The application is developed with C# and WPF.
I have a data binding to a static property of a non static class.
When the application is started, the binding does well, but if i change the bool of the binding, the view is not been updated.
How can i update the binding of this static property ?
NotifyChanged-Events don't affected.

The class:

```
public class ViewTemplateManager : NotifyBase
{
    public static bool CanResizeColumns { get; set; }

    static ViewTemplateManager()
    {
        CanResizeColumns = true;
    }
```

The View:

```
<Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=viewManager:ViewTemplateManager.CanResizeColumns}}"
```

Comment: I don't understand why this class is static. You could use inheritance or composibility to combine this with a base class of your viewmodel. If you do that, you will have that CanResizeColumns as Property on your viewmodel and successfully use OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you have a reference to the associated [BindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx).

Assuming you have a reference to the Thumb in your code, it would look like:

```
var bindingExpression = thumb.GetBindingExpression(Thumb.IsEnabledProperty);
if (bindingExpression != null)
    bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```

Your best bet would be to use a singleton pattern, like so:

```
public class ViewTemplateManager : NotifyBase
{
    public bool CanResizeColumns { get; set; }

    public static ViewTemplateManager Instance { get; private set; }

    static ViewTemplateManager()
    {
        Instance = new ViewTemplateManager();
    }

    private ViewTemplateManager()
    {
        CanResizeColumns = true;
    }
}
```

Then bind like so:

```
<Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static viewManager:ViewTemplateManager.Instance}, Path=CanResizeColumns}}"
```

Then you simply need to raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event when you change CanResizeColumns.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no direct equivalent to the notification mechanism of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for a static property.

There are a couple of options, including:

1. Make an instance level property that returns the static member.  Use a custom mechanism to notify instances of the change, at which time the instance can raise the `PropertyChanged` event.  This can get ugly and introduce memory leaks if you're not careful about unsubscribing or using a Weak Event pattern.
2. Move the static property into a singleton, and place it as an instance member on the singleton instance.  This allows that instance to raise `PropertyChanged` events as normal.

Comment: There is `StaticPropertyChanged`

Comment: @wobbles was added after this answer 

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement the properties using a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) on which the property is not static or you just also make it non-static but you just create one instance in the `App` instance for example (i would go with the latter). In either case you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier solution:

Class property:

```
private static bool isEnabled; //there is Your static

public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return isEnabled; }
    set
    {
        isEnabled = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnabled"); //OnPropertyChanged or something
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```