# Binding to a property within a static class instance

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

**What I am trying to achieve**

I have a WPF application (it's just for testing) and I want to bind the text (Content) of a label to a property somewhere. The idea is that this property value will be changed when the user chooses a different language. When the property changes, I want the label text to update with the new value.

**What I have tried**

I tried to create a static class with a static property for the label value. For example:

```
public static class Language
{
    public static string Name = "Name";
}
```

I then was able to bind this value to my label using XAML like so:

```
Content="{Binding Source={x:Static lang:Language.Name}}"
```

And this worked fine for showing the initial value of "Name". The problem is, when the `Name` property changes the label value doesn't change.

So, back to the drawing board (Google). Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390863/838807) which sounded exactly like what I needed. So here was my new attempt at this:

```
public class Language
{
    public static Language Instance { get; private set; }
    static Language() { Instance = new Language(); }
    private Language() { }

    private string name = "Name";
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
}
```

With my binding changed it this:

```
Content="{Binding Source={x:Static lang:Language.Instance}, Path=Name}"
```

This still results in the same problem.

**Questions**

What am I missing here? How can I get the label to update when the value is changed?

Comment: Binding engine works with properties. All code samples contains *a field* Name, not a *property*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That simply isn't a property. Try:

```
public class Language
{
    public static Language Instance { get; private set; }
    static Language() { Instance = new Language(); }
    private Language() { Name = "Name"; }

    public string Name {get;private set;}
}
```

or with change notification:

```
public class Language : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static Language Instance { get; private set; }
    static Language() { Instance = new Language(); }
    private Language() { }

    private string name = "Name";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetValue(ref name, value);}
    }
    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: OK, I had initial tried this by just doing `... Name {get;set;}` which as expected was still blank, but I was expecting it to change when I set it through the "change language" option. Testing by giving it a default value (as you just suggested) does work initially, but I still have the problem as with the original attempt, how to make the label update when the property changes?

Comment: @musefan to do *that* you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Sorry, I have now changed my question. My problem was misleading because I was coding it wrong with the property attempt. My question ultimately is about the change to the property. My research into INotifyPropertyChanged seems to be a bit of a headache if I have a lot of different label properties. So I was looking for a simplier approach, which got me where I am now

Comment: @musefan if you have a lot of properties, there's a neat trick - I'll edit that in

Comment: Got it working. I wasn't sure what `CallerMemberName` was (I didn't even know you could put attributes on parameters), but it seems to work fine without it... is there any particular reason you included it? Am I going to get a problem later down the line without it?